# jquery: nested tags and hover() not working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, nested, hover

i have a construction like this:

```
<div id="container">

<span>
   <span></span>
</span>

<span>
   <span></span>
</span>

</div>
```

i need to catch the mouseout event of the container, so i made jquery do this:

```
$("#container").hover('',function(){ 
alert("Out"); 
});
```

In Firefox / Opera, it only fires the mouseout-function when leaving the div
(how I want it).

In IE it fires the mouseout-function at every *-Tag inside of the div the mouse hits.
(*maybe important is, that the span tags have also mouseover and out events)

Anyone has an idea how to solve this?
(The nested structure cant be changed because a complex layout)

thx4 any ideas!

Comment: Though we could figure it out ourselves, it would help to know which version of IE you are inquiring about.

Answer (score 5):

@evelio: it didnt work, the id was always "container"

how i solved it (so far...):

believe it or not, the attribute background-color of the container-div had to be set in a color. 
im still quite shocked of this fact but i tryed it several times and its only the background-color attribute in the css that makes it work or not.

and: the color #000000 does not work, any other color does, including "white"

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for sniffing this one out, I'd have never gotten it.

Comment: At first I thought you were kidding, until it solved it for me too! Thanks and also, WTH, IE??

Comment: Looks like a transparent gif can also be used.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $("#container").hover('',function(ev){

      alert("Out");
      if( ev.stopPropagation ) { ev.stopPropagation(); } //For 'Good' browsers
      else { ev.cancelBubble = true; } //For IE

 });
```

also read: [Event bubbling and capturing](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/06/30/event-delegation-in-javascript/)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$("#container").mouseleave(function(){ 
alert("Out"); 
});
```

As for IE, boycott the crappy browser and make blogs about its sheer hopelessness until your fingers go numb. That browser is responsible for web designers' time being worth about 33% less than it should be. Just kill it any way you can.

Answer (score 1):

The way you can solve it is adding a 1px transparant png as background.

See: [IE8: Div hover only works when background color is set, very strange, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998917/ie8-div-hover-only-works-when-background-color-is-set-very-strange-why)

Answer (score 0):

Mhhh I don't have IE near but you can try the [jQuery mouseout demos](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/mouseout) (and hover demos) if it works fine seems to be a trouble with your code in some other line... finally you can workaroud it with:

```
$("#container").hover('',function()
{
    //Are you sure?
    if($(this).attr('id') == 'container')
    {
        alert('yup this is container');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
$("#container").hover('',function(){ 
    alert("Out"); 
    return false;
});
```

or:

```
$("#container").hover('',function(e){ 
    if($(e.target).is("#container")){
        alert("Out"); 
        return false;
    }
});
```

or better still:

```
$("#container").mouseout(function(e){ 
    if($(e.target).is("#container")){
        alert("Out"); 
        return false;
    }
});
```

If you only need the mouseout there is no reason to use the hover function.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in IE 6, 7, and 8. Mafka is right, the background color has to be set to make it work. If it’s not feasible to set a background color on your “container”, you can still set the background color to white and set the opacity to 0.

I’ve done this with the following JavaScript code *before* binding the mouseover Event in jQuery:

```
if ($.browser.msie) {
    $("#container").css({
        background: '#fff',
        opacity: 0
    });
}
```