# IE8: Div hover only works when background color is set, very strange, why?

Tags: jquery, css, html, hover, transparent

**Situation:** Got a div with buttons images. Div needs to fadeIn on hover. Works in all browsers, except Internet Explorer. When I give the div a background color it suddenly works.

Check: http://ListAndPlay.com , top left are the controls.

The hover won't work in IE, try to add a background color to #buttons and it suddenly works.

**Question:** What is the reason for this? How to fix this properly?

Comment: Very ugly bugfix: add transparent image as background...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I recently ran in to this problem also. I also solved it by adding a 1 by 1 px transparent background image to the hover element. I felt like taking a shower afterwards.

Comment: I had to take a shower, too. I did have a solution with a `background: transparent` but I may have been fooling myself -- someone may want to play around with this one.

Answer (score 10):

I had this issue just today making a `transparent` overlay div appear when hovered on. IE9 wouldn't activate hover until the mouse was over the text content of the overlay. Worked fine on Chrome and FF4. I didn't try the transparent image workaround, but this seemed to work just fine: `rgba(0,0,0,0)`. Weird...

Comment: Nice find, and way better than using a transparent image. And yes, weird :)

Comment: this wont work in IE6, 7, 8 as they dont support rgba the best approach is to use a 2x2 transparent png

Answer (score 5):

My solution is to set a background color on the element you need to hover, then use the CSS `opacity` property to hide it. A fallback is provided for IE in the form of a filter.

```
.element {
  background-color: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=1);
}
```

This solution doesn't require a transparent PNG, and unlike the rgba solution it works in older versions of IE.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to has layout. Using position:relative will give the same result without use of a unwanted background image.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue. For me, the problem seemed to be related to using html5 elements  (e.g. `<footer>` and `header`) in ie8, and forgetting to use [html5shiv](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv) to add support for those elements for older browsers.

In this case, adding the html5shiv solved the problem. None of the other proposed solutions had any effect.

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same problem with IE8 using HTML5. My solution was inspired by Herman's. I set a background image and then I'm creating background from non-existing part of it. Basically, I'm asking the browser to display something that is beyond image's dimensions.

```
background: url(myimage.png) 300px 0px no-repeat;
```

To avoid unnecessary traffic it can be website's sprite or any other valid image that it's already being used on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Even with the latest version of IE9 I have this same issue. As **MeProtozoan** suggested, adding a transparent background image to the anchor(s) gets the behavior working as desired, but *damn* it's dirty.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with hover in div not working in IE8 and changing my doctype to

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

fixed it.

[More details here](http://forums.techguy.org/web-design-development/903960-css-menu-not-working-ie8.html)