# How t make work DIV:hover in IE8

Tags: html, css

please tell me how to make DIV:Hover work in IE 8

Comment: What have you tried?  What specific issues are you running into?  Do you have any sample code to provide?

Answer (score 2):

Add a transparent background image to the div, or add position: relative.

For more details, see [IE8: Div hover only works when background color is set, very strange, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998917/ie8-div-hover-only-works-when-background-color-is-set-very-strange-why) .