# CSS :hover selects the wrong element in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, hover

So here's something I have to get to work in IE8 without the use of jQuery.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
<area id="clickable-area" alt="" title="" href="#" shape="rect" coords="183,284,224,322" style="outline:none;" target="_self" class="hover" />
<p id="text-hover">Text</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper #text-hover {
  position:absolute;
  color: #ecbf96;
  top:30px;
  left:30px;
  visibility:hidden;
}

#wrapper:hover #text-hover { //:hover selects #wrapper in every
  visibility:visible;          //browser other than IE, where it ends
}                            //up selecting #text-hover instead
```

Any ideas what might cause this behaviour in IE8 and how to get around it?

Comment: Could you prepare JS Fiddle for that?

Comment: What do you mean by it selecting the wrong element? Do you mean you have to hover over #text-hover instead of #wrapper in IE?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998917/ie8-div-hover-only-works-when-background-color-is-set-very-strange-why

Similar question, please try.

Comment: Make sure you declared your doctype correctly.

Comment: @AustinCollins Yes, that's exactly what the issue is.

Comment: @NubPro Already tried that method, original issue still remains.

Comment: @Enrico I checked and tried different doctypes people suggested to use. No results, I don't think my issue is related.

Comment: This could be related to the browser not being able to render div#wrapper correctly. I'm not that skilled in IE8 but having the complete source might help identify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**#text-hover** element is absolute positioned. Absolutely positioned elements are removed from the normal flow. The document and other elements behave like the absolutely positioned element does not exist. In this case it seems #wrapper element's height is 0px, so it is invisible actually. 
Try

```
#wrapper #text-hover{position: relative;}
```

OR

```
#wrapper{
    height: 20px; /* or some other value which is bigger than 0 */
}
```